# Using Cursor respond and getExtras not working?

Tags: android

I'm designing a ContentProvider which needs to return a cursor with data and I need to know the status of that data.

I need a status for the cursor data since this data was downloaded and I need to know if it only downloaded partial data or if during the download some of the elements weren't downloaded. It's a bit more complex but you might get the idea why I need a status for my cursor data.

So I have reviewed the source code for all Cursor implementations in Android and it seems `getExtras` and `respond` functions are plain garbage since they don't do anything internally...  Also, there seems to be missing a `setExtras` function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that the method is not setExtras(), but respond().

I'm not sure what you mean by the "status of the data", but it sounds like you want to know if the columns in the cursor are clean or not. Most content provider implementations I've seen put this type of status into the rows themselves, or store it in a separate table. I don't think you should try attaching the status to the Cursor itself.

Just so you know, if you want to get notification when the data underlying the cursor changes, you can use setNotificationUri(), registerContentObserver, or registerDataSetObserver().

Notice that nothing requires you to make the columns you provide from a content provider be the same as the columns in any underlying database you use. You could add a column that the provider itself generates, and store status in that.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I think overall the Cursor setExtras and respond aren't properly developed and supported. Looking at the source: 
public Bundle respond(Bundle extras) {
        return Bundle.EMPTY;
    }
However, I guess I'll have to store the status on a new column.